# my iOS apps not showing in Brazil App Store

Tags: ios, localization, app-store

I have three applications available on App Store. The applications belongs to following Categories : `Music,Travel & Entertainment` , but non of my applications are available for `Brazilian App Store`. Now my question is -

- Is it possible to make my apps available for `Brazilian App Store` without submitting new build.
- If it required new binary to upload, then what are the necessary steps.

Comment: Consult with the Dev team on this. Maybe the app store has limits by the Brazilian government. I'm referring to this as my country has Appstore limits as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because app store submission policy is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/65839) and better addressed by Apple support.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Login to **itunesconnect.apple.com**
> 2. Then Select My Apps > **Your App**
> 3. Then navigate to App Store Tab under that select **Pricing and Availability**
> 4. Select **Edit** option in front of Available in all territories.
> 5. **Choose the Countries** you want to have your app and Save

**Note:** *Also make sure that if want to download the app from particular countries app store then you must have logged in with such apple id that having that country address inside your iTunes & App Store in iPhone Device. Unless you will able to see the app in your iPhone.*

[image]

Comment: One thing is you can check with iTunes dev team, and ask them the reason. Else upload a new binary. But the app once available is online in all territories.